# grouping data from multiple tables using linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4

I am joining couple tables and trying to get the count of each status.

`EmployeeEvaluationsStatuses` has the following fields :

Id, Title.

Data in `EmployeeEvaluationsStatuses` look like :

```
Id  Title
1   New - Incomplete
2   Submitted – All Docs
3   Approved
4   Rejected - Need More Info
5   Qualified
```

I want to get the result as follows :

```
StatusCount  Status

60           New - Incomplete 
42           Submitted – All Docs 
20           Qualified
```

Here is how my query look like :

```
from ep in EmployeePositions.Where(a => a.CorporateId == 1596)
join ee in EmployeeEvaluations.Where(e => e.TargetGroupId != null) on ep.EmployeeId equals ee.EmployeeId
join ees in EmployeeEvaluationStatuses  on ee.EvaluationStatusId  equals ees.Id

group ees by ees.Id into g
select new
{
   StatusCount = g.Count()
   ,Status= ees .title      
}
```

I am getting an error "`The name 'ees' does not exist in the current context`"

I am not sure about navigational properties.

```
 public partial class WotcEntities : DbContext
    {
        public WotcEntities()
       : base(hr.common.Database.EntitiesConnectionString("res://*/ef.WotcModel.csdl|res://*/ef.WotcModel.ssdl|res://*/ef.WotcModel.msl", "devConnection"))
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }


      public virtual DbSet<EmployeeEvaluations> EmployeeEvaluations { get; set; }
      public virtual DbSet<EmployeeEvaluationStatus> EmployeeEvaluationStatus { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<EmployeePositions> EmployeePositions { get; set; }

    }




public partial class EmployeeEvaluationStatus
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public EmployeeEvaluationStatus()
        {
            this.EmployeeEvaluations = new HashSet<EmployeeEvaluations>();
            this.Vouchers = new HashSet<Vouchers>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<EmployeeEvaluations> EmployeeEvaluations { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Vouchers> Vouchers { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have navigational properties between your entities? Can you show your entity classes?

Comment: I added the entity classses which present under entityFramework.

Comment: You seem to have navigational properties. Can you show `EmployeePositions` and `EmployeeEvaluations`?

Comment: Navigational properties allow you to write the query in a much easier and readable way.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a composite key in your `group by` and navigate using `g.Key`

```
from ep in EmployeePositions.Where(a => a.CorporateId == 1596)
join ee in EmployeeEvaluations.Where(e => e.TargetGroupId != null) on ep.EmployeeId equals ee.EmployeeId
join ees in EmployeeEvaluationStatuses on ee.EvaluationStatusId  equals ees.Id

group ees by new { ees.Id, ees.title } into g
select new
{
    StatusCount = g.Count(),
    Status= g.Key.title
}
```